# HTTP AUTHORIZATION API works in POSTMAN but not in react native

Tags: php, react-native, authorization

The whole thing works in POSTMAN where I am able to retrieve the information but somehow it stuck in my react native application.

PHP Code for getting the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_API key.

```
$request_header = $request->getHeaders();
if ($data_validation->validate_authentication_api($request_header['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_API'][0], $response)) {
... [i do my calling here]
}
```

React Native Code

```
const response = await fetch(
    `URL`,
       {
        headers: {
             'AUTHORIZATION_AP': 'myKEY'
        }
       }
);
```

Can't figure out what wrong as POSTMAN is working fine

Comment: google how to get errors from fetch. or any HTTP request for that matter.. And then read it... and then use it, and you can edit your post if that error is unclear to you. You ALWAYS need to use error-catching... And make additional logic based on that...

Comment: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/

Comment: The error was the API key is null

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Simply just REACT NATIVE does not recognize underscore in between words for headers.

hence I just put

```
const response = await fetch(
    `URL`,
       {
        headers: {
             'AUTHORIZATION': 'myKEY'
        }
       }
);
```

While your PHP code change FROM

```
$request_header['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_API'[0]
```

TO

```
$request_header['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'][0]
```

HTTP_ is automatically added in front of AUTHORIZATION. It is the syntax of headers